# Login Portlet Hook, class not found PwdEncryptor

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I create a hook for login portlet.

I have problem with this line of code:

```
String encPwd = PwdEncryptor.encrypt(password, user.getPassword());
```

The class PwdEncryptor not found and package `com.liferay.portal.security.pwd` does not exist

I use a Liferay 6.0.6 plugin to create a hook and i read this:

[Developing a CAS](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System) (Custom Authentication System)

and:

https://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14773767

> PwdEncryptor is in portal-impl.jar so it's not visible to plugins. What you could use is PortalClassInvoker to invoke it. If you need example check out com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.PortletActionInvoker class.

I don't know what to do with this invoker, where to call it or use it.

Comment: Finished: I integrade them in the project: PwdEncryptor and Crypt.

Answer (score 0):

integrade PwdEncryptor and Crypt.

Comment: after protected int authenticate i get get SUCCESS, but i still can not go in. Can you help?